# How to create user in AD and SharePoint using C#

Tags: development

Any ideas how to create user in AD in asp.net application, in the same time add that user to a group in SharePoint?

Comment: is your asp.net application will run on sharepoint server or will it run remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding user using C#, below is code sample:

```
using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
  using(var up = new UserPrincipal(pc))
  {
    up.SamAccountName = username;
    up.EmailAddress = email;
    up.SetPassword(password);
    up.Enabled = true;
    up.ExpirePasswordNow();
    up.Save();
  }
}
```

[See MSDN link for full code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384369.aspx).

For adding user in SharePoint Group,below is sample code:

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Add a user to a Sharepoint group
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userLoginName">Login name of the user to add</param>
        /// <param name="userGroupName">Group name to add</param>
        private void AddUserToAGroup(string userLoginName, string userGroupName)
        {
            //Executes this method with Full Control rights even if the user does not otherwise have Full Control
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            {

                using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("your site address"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Allow updating of some sharepoint lists, (here spUsers, spGroups etc...)
                            spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                            SPUser spUser = spWeb.EnsureUser(userLoginName);

                            if (spUser != null)
                            {
                                SPGroup spGroup = spWeb.Groups[userGroupName];

                                if (spGroup != null)
                                    spGroup.AddUser(spUser);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Error handling logic should go here
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
```